# Sublime 2 Java build

Tags: java, linux, sublimetext2, javac

Hi i am using this build system that i found here on so but for some reason it is still not working, the output i get is the javac options i have used this build system.I have used the default one with no luck had a look on-line and couldn't find much.

```
{
  "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","java", "$file_base_name"],
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
  "selector": "source.java",
  "shell": true
}
```

is there a better build system that i can use??

Comment: what is the output you are getting? Did you save your file before building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this. It works for me.

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && java $file_base_name && rm *.class"],
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell": true,
    "variants": [

        {
            "name": "JavaDoc",
            "cmd": ["mkdir documentation && javadoc -d documentation *.java"]
        },

        {
            "name": "JAR",
            "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && echo \"Main-Class: $file_base_name\" > Manifest.txt && jar cfm $file_base_name.jar Manifest.txt *.class && rm *.class && java -jar $file_base_name.jar"]
        },


    ]
}
```

This works for me on Linux and can be downloaded on Github at [Java.sublime-build](https://gist.github.com/tushortz/5fc717d4bddedf5b560b)

The interesting thing is that it also compile files to JAR. Remove classes  after compilation to make things neater and it also support generating JavaDocs.

The only limitation is that it cannot accept user input or arguments at compile time. You would have to do that manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 comes with a build system for Java, you need to select it from Tools -> Build Systems -> Java. Make sure you have the path of jdk/bin and "." in your system paths(classpath & path).

If you want it to be able to run java code instead of just compiling it, follow these steps:

Make the bat file with the following, and save it anywhere in your PATH. I suggest C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin\ to keep everything together.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %~dp1
javac %~nx1
java %~n1
```

then edit C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Java\JavaC.sublime-build, the contents will be

```
{
   "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java"
}
```

replace "javac" with the name of your bat file (for instance, javacexec.bat) and save it.

Now you should be able to run it using ctrl+b.